# Android supportsRtl makes negative num view with minus after the number

Tags: android, right-to-left, signed

When adding on my androidManifest: `android:supportsRtl="true"`
my `TextView` with text "-1390" is shown as "1390-"

how can I fix it?

(edit) This is my current problematic textView:

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_account_balance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"
                android:text="\u200F -10,452"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textDirection="rtl"        *ltr did not work as well*
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Comment: try setting the `android:inputType` to number
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but for those who need an answer, just try to wrap you number with:

```
"\u202D your number \u202C"
```

This will do the work.

Comment: The best solution. tnx

Comment: this works fine. but could you explain how?

Comment: @mrzbn https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-unicode-controls#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20change%20the%20direction%20for%20a%20run%20of%20inline%20text%20you%20need%20to%20indicate%20a%20start%20and%20end%20point.%20For%20this%20you%20need%20to%20use%20one%20of%20the%20following%20characters%20to%20indicate%20the%20start%20of%20the%20embedded%20direction%20change.

Answer (score 3):

You can override this behavior by specifying `android:textDirection="ltr"` on the `TextView`. You can also set that attribute on the root `ViewGroup` of your layout, if you want all of the textual `View`s it contains to layout their text left-to-right.

Comment: Why do you have the RTL MARK - `\u200F` - at the beginning of the text? Also, you'll probably need to rebuild the project after changing the XML.

Comment: the question want to be RTL but works properly for negative number. in RTL languages you should number in LTR because it's standard of math. so that does not help

Comment: @SiavashAbdoli I don't understand what you're saying. I don't even remember this question, but my answer was apparently posted before the OP provided the XML, and they never did reply to my question concerning the RTL MARK.

Comment: @SiavashAbdoli Also, your statement about RTL languages in general doesn't appear to be correct. It seems that there are RTL languages in which the negative sign is placed to the right.

Comment: @MikeM. No bro I'm speaking persian and developing app in persian for 6 years. I have the same problem here and making whole textview ltr is not the solution because it's combined with persian text and number

Comment: @SiavashAbdoli OK, but Persian isn't the only RTL language in the world, so your blanket statement about "in RTL languages you should number in LTR" is not wholly correct. Furthermore, the question doesn't even mention a particular language, and was specifically about a `TextView` with only a number in it. That's all my answer was meant to address. If they'd asked how to override that behavior for all mixed text everywhere, I wouldn't have suggested this.

Comment: @MikeM. math has its own standards. which RTL language write negative 2 like 2-? I didn't see that.

Comment: @SiavashAbdoli Sorry, but I'm not going digging for that again. If you'd asked sooner, rather than only responding every 4 to 5 days, I might've linked you to the results of my research. It's completely irrelevant to the question here, anyway, since the point is to get the negative sign on the left, which I showed how to do for the specific setup given in the question.

Comment: @MikeM. btw as you can see in edited question your answer does not work. he/she wants to set textDirection to rtl as default in his/her xml and as he/she mentioned ltr doesn't work neither.

Comment: @SiavashAbdoli "you can see in edited question your answer does not work." – The edited question contains information not in the original, which I addressed in comments here. "he/she wants to set textDirection to rtl as default in his/her xml" – Frankly, you don't know exactly what they want, unless you're the OP on a different account. Furthermore, if they do want `rtl` as the layout default, that's fine, because they can still override that per element, as shown. "he/she mentioned ltr doesn't work neither." – No, `ltr` _does_ work if they remove the RTL MARK from the text.

Answer (score -1):

android:supportsRtl Declares whether your application is willing to support right-to-left (RTL) layouts. If set to true and targetSdkVersion is set to 17 or higher, various RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so your app can display RTL layouts. If set to false or if targetSdkVersion is set to 16 or lower, the RTL APIs will be ignored or will have no effect and your app will behave the same regardless of the layout direction associated to the user's Locale choice (your layouts will always be left-to-right). The default value of this attribute is false. This attribute was added in API level 17.

now you know that text is show right to left view..

Comment: ok fine..i misunderstood you can follow the next answer for that

Comment: out of context!
the question want to be RTL but works properly for negative number. in RTL languages you should number in LTR because it's standard of math. so that does not help